# Не работает команда manage.py startapp

Tags: python, pycharm

Ввожу в консоль команду:

```
manage.py startapp lesson_one
```

чтобы создать приложение, в итоге в Pycharm.
`manage.py` открывается и всё, больше ничего не происходит, ошибки никакие не появляются.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы запускали и на python2, и на python3? Если на одной версии, то ее в метке ставьте

Comment: @ gil9red простите за глупый вопрос, но как это сделать?

Comment: Как определить версию питона или как указать метку после создания вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй `python manage.py startapp lesson_one`
либо:

`python2 manage.py startapp lesson_one`
`python3 manage.py startapp lesson_one`

Comment: ваш вариант не помог, но я ещё раз попробовал вставить прежнюю команду и всё заработало. Не понимаю даже в чем собственно была ошибка, команду в принципе не менял.

Comment: Теперь понял в чем была проблема надо было указать в начале команды `python` в результате команда должна принять вид   `python manage.py startapp lesson_one`, в начале не обратил внимание, что @stdian мне это отписал выше.